# Assertion on Compactness

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

I'm trying to prove the following:

"Let $f :X\rightarrow f(X) $ be a continuous, 2-to-1 function, $X$ metric space.

If $F\subset X$ is a closed, non compact subspace, then $f(F)$ is non compact$.

At first, I tried decomposing $X$ into the disjoint union $X=A \cup B$, such that $f |_A$ and $f |_B$ are injective.

Then the subset $F$ could be written as $F= (F\cap A)\cup(F \cap B)$.

The thing is, I'm trying to use that "$f:X \rightarrow f(X)$ is injective, continuous function, and $F \subset X$ is closed, non compact set, then $f(F)$ is non- compact"

But, in order to do that, I need $A$ or $B$ to be closed.

Do you have any ideas to fulfill the attempt? Or am I in the wrong direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think this is true?

Comment: Also, the quoted statement that you say you are trying to use is false.  Perhaps you have omitted some assumption?

Comment: ? and in the second line, you assumed that $f$ is two-to-one, meaning that for each $y\in f(X)$, there are exactly two $x_1,x_2$ s.t. $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, which is not injective...(but you were trying to use that $f$ is injective in the 7th line...)

Comment: @EricWofsey It was stated on an article. 
Is the quoted statement really not true?

Comment: @Kevin.S Yes, I'm trying to prove the 2 to 1 case assuming the injective case is true

Comment: @MateusRhodes: Yes, for instance let $Y$ be any infinite compact metric space, let $X$ be $Y$ with the discrete metric, and let $f:X\to Y$ be the identity map.

Comment: @EricWofsey Fair enough... thank you. I'll check if there are additional assumptions

Comment: @EricWofsey Hey Eric... shouldn't be the domain non compact in your counter example?

Comment: An infinite discrete space is not compact.

Comment: my fault... thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a counterexample . . .

Let metric spaces $X,Y$ be given by
\begin{align*}
X&=\mathbb{Z}\,{\large{\setminus}}\{0\}\\[4pt]
Y&=\{0\}\cup\Bigl\{{\small{\frac{1}{n}}}{\;{\Large{\mid}}\;}n=2,3,4,...\Bigr\}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
with metrics inherited from the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}$.

Note that the topology on $X$ is discrete, so every subset of $X$ is both open and closed.

Regarding compactness,

- Every infinite subset of $X$ is non-compact.$\\[4pt]$

  Every closed subset of $Y$ is compact.

Let $f:X\to Y$ be defined by
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0&\text{if}\;|x|=1\\[4pt]
{\Large{\frac{1}{|x|}}}&\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
$$
Then $f$ is a continuous $2$-to-$1$ function from $X$ onto $Y$.

Now let $F$ be any infinite subset of $X$ such that $F\cap\{-1,1\}\ne{\large{\varnothing}}$.

Then $F$ is closed but not compact, whereas $f(F)$ is compact.

Comment: Thank you so much. 

Based on your experience, what adiditional assumptions  do you think would make the assertion true?

Comment: @Mateus R.: Perhaps assuming that $X$ is connected would work. I'm not sure.

Comment: @Mateus R.: In what context did the problem arise?

Comment: It is stated as true in an article, I want to certify its validity

Comment: For instance, if you'd like to check it: "On metric invariants of entropy type", by A.G. Kushnirenko

Comment: would you like me to clarify the full context by dm?

Comment: @Mateus R.: Perhaps ask it as a new question with a link back to this one.