# Assertion on Compactness 2

Tags: general-topology

I saw an affirmation about compactness on this article, without proof, and I'm trying to understand why it is true ( if it is).

Here it is:

"Let $f:X→f(X)$ be a continuous, 2-to-1 function, $X$ metric space.

If $F⊂X$ is a closed, non compact subspace, then $f(F)$ is non compact."

I asked previously the same question, without the article context, and it was answered properly with counterexemples  ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4042777/assertion-on-compactness)).

The article can be found here([2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17Z3-ntYvR6c_FfzmxJyg5KoJmSjrv-fJ/view?usp=sharing)). The affirmation is located at page 7, right before the "2nd lemma".

Am I missing any hypotheses or assumptions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Papers *can* be wrong. Maybe this is a case in point.

Comment: He doe mention some formula with $\rho$ and some logs as well, and the way I read it, the statement follows mostly from the formula not only the 2-1 bit. So you must use analytical tools too, it seems.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma It might be wrong, but I don't think this is very likely, because the final result was used in other papers by well known mathematicians

Comment: @HennoBrandsma The only thing I took from the \rho identity was the affirmative that \varphi is continuous... But yeah, there shall be some analytical reasoning behind it.